# HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

I'm having trouble with my app. I created the forms, the user after clicking "save" should go to the list of saved activities unfortunately it does not and I get the following problem,HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request
Type Status Report

Description The server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing).

Apache Tomcat/9.0.37

I tried @RestController but it does not work. I'd be grateful for your help

This is my module class Clean

```
@ToString
@Entity
@Table(name = "clean")
public class Clean {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Long id;

   @NotBlank
   private String clean;



   public Long getId() {
       return id;
   }

   public void setId(Long id) {
       this.id = id;
   }

   public String getClean() {
       return clean;
   }

   public void setClean(String clean) {
       this.clean = clean;
   }
}
```

FormController

```
@Controller
public class CleanFormController {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final CleanRepository cleanRepository;
    private final WeekRepository weekRepository;

    public CleanFormController(UserRepository userRepository, CleanRepository cleanRepository, WeekRepository weekRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.cleanRepository = cleanRepository;
        this.weekRepository = weekRepository;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/clean/form")
    public String getCleanForm(Model model) {
        Clean clean = new Clean();
        model.addAttribute("clean", clean);
        return "cleanForm";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/clean/remove/{id}")
    public String deleteById(@PathVariable Long id) {
        cleanRepository.removeClean(id);
        return "redirect:/clean/list";
    }



    @RequestMapping(value = "/clean/form", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String postClean(@ModelAttribute @Valid Clean clean, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "cleanForm";
        }
        cleanRepository.saveClean(clean);
        return "redirect:/clean/list";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/clean/list", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String allClean(Model model) {
        List<Clean> cleanList = cleanRepository.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("cleans", cleanList);
        return "cleanList";
    }
}
```

Repository

```
public class CleanRepository {


    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;

    public Clean saveClean(Clean clean) {
        if (clean.getId() == null) {
            entityManager.persist(clean);
        } else {
            entityManager.merge(clean);
        }
        return clean;

    }

    public Clean readClean(Long id){
        return entityManager.find(Clean.class, id);
    }

    public Clean updateClean (Clean clean){
        entityManager.merge(clean);
        return clean;
    }

    public void removeClean(Long id) {
        Clean clean = entityManager.find(Clean.class, id);
        entityManager.remove(entityManager.contains(clean) ? clean : entityManager.merge(clean));

    }

    public List<Clean> findAll() {
        Query query = entityManager.createQuery("Select t from Clean t");
        return query.getResultList();
    }

    public Clean findById(Long id) {
        return entityManager.find(Clean.class, id);
    }

}
```

Controller

```
@Transactional
@Controller
public class CleanController {

    private final CleanRepository cleanRepository;

    public CleanController(CleanRepository cleanRepository) {
        this.cleanRepository = cleanRepository;
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = {"/add/clean"})
    @ResponseBody
    public String home() {
        Clean clean = new Clean();
        clean.setId(1l);
        clean.setClean("Ironing");
        cleanRepository.saveClean(clean);
        return "Clean: " + clean.getId();
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/clean/read/{id}")
    @ResponseBody
    public String readClean(@PathVariable long id) {
        Clean clean = cleanRepository.findById(id);
        return clean.toString();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/clean/update/{id}/{name}")
    @ResponseBody
    public String updateClean(@PathVariable long id, @PathVariable String name) {
        Clean clean = cleanRepository.findById(id);
        clean.setClean(name);
        cleanRepository.updateClean(clean);
        return clean.toString();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/clean/delete/{id}")
    @ResponseBody
    public String removeClean(@PathVariable long id) {
        Clean clean = cleanRepository.findById(id);
        return "Removed this clean";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/clean/all"})
    @ResponseBody
    public String cleanAll () {
        List<Clean> all = cleanRepository.findAll();
        return "Cleans: " + all.size();
    }
}
```

cleanForm

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<style>
    error {
        background-color: red;
    }
</style>
<body>

<form:form method="post" modelAttribute="clean" action="/clean/form">

            <p hidden><form:input path="id"/></p>

            <label for="clean">Clean</label>
            <form:input path="clean" id="clean"/>
            <form:errors path="clean" cssClass="error"/>

            <br>

            <input type="submit" value="Save">
        </form:form>

</body>
</html>
```

cleanList

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>

<table>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Clean</th>


        <c:forEach items="${cleans}" var="clean">
    <tr>
        <td>${clean.id}</td>
        <td>${clean.clean}</td>
    </tr>

    </c:forEach>
</table>

<a href="form">Add cleans</a>


</html>
```

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo That is a style improvement, and there are many that could be made here, but it's not the cause of the problem. OP, be aware that you seem to be using outdated tutorials and design here; I recommend reading the official Spring Getting Started Guides for Spring Boot.

Answer (score 1):

Use @Autowired on  constructor which is inside controller

Answer (score 0):

Change these two methods :

```
    @GetMapping(value = "/clean/form")
    public String getCleanForm(Model model) {
        Clean clean = new Clean();
        model.addAttribute("clean", clean);
        return "cleanForm";
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/clean/form")
    public String postClean(@ModelAttribute @Valid Clean clean, BindingResult
            bindingResult) {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "cleanForm";
        }
        cleanRepository.saveClean(clean);
        return "redirect:/clean/list";
    }
```

Comment: Thank You for your answer but it is not working there are the same fail

Comment: There is no problem with method but in forms but thank You for yours help

Answer (score 0):

On the click of submit button of the form, it tries to go "/clean/form" URL but in the controller, this below code snippet is executed before going to the actual method which is  @RequestMapping(value = "/clean/form", method = RequestMethod.POST). Because the @RequestMapping(value = "/clean/form") this will accept any request.

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/clean/form")
    public String getCleanForm(Model model) {
        Clean clean = new Clean();
        model.addAttribute("clean", clean);
        return "cleanForm";
    }
```

So to overcome this, you have two possible ways to change first one is to change RequestMapping of the above code to GetMapping or you can change the form action URL and @RequestMapping(value = "/clean/form", method = RequestMethod.POST) URL accordingly.

Comment: Hi,Thank You for yours answer but unfortunately it's still the same fail

Comment: Hi again, there is no problem with method but in forms I have the same name of path so I had to change this and now everything is ok Thank You again for answers